# Oracle SQL query joining same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table like this:

```
                 items
id            old_new     object 

1               o         pen
2               n         house
3               o         dog
4               o         cat
5               n         carrot
```

I would like the select  return:

```
id    new_object     old_object

1        null          pen
2        house        null
3        null         dog
4        null         cat  
5        carrot       null
```

Do I need to use an outer join on the same table?

Answer (score 2):

No join needed:

```
select id, 
       case when old_new = 'n' then object end as new_object,
       case when old_new = 'o' then object end as old_object
from the_table
order by id;
```

Comment: How would this get the results OP wants? It would just return the old_new column wich is just N or O